# PHP SimpleXML size limit

Tags: php

I'm using simpleXML and PHP to get a feed, then processing it in a foreach loop as normal.

I would like to recognise if the feed is huge and stop the processing of the feed, or if possible, stop the downloading of the feed completely, or cut it once it is over a set limit.

Are there any methods to do this?

Comment: No. SimpleXML will attempt to suck up the entire XML document in one go. To parse xml files which will potentially exceed memory limits, use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167062/best-way-to-process-large-xml-in-php

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XMLReader](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) for this

Answer (score 0):

1. Download to Your tmp folder or check the size with [curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602612/php-remote-file-size-without-downloading-file)
2. Check the [filesize](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.filesize.php)
3. Parse it