# Parsing very big XML file with PHP

Tags: php, xml-parsing, simplexml, saxparser

I am trying to parse an 5GB XML File with PHP. Every one parser is trying to alocate this 5 GB as first and then start to work. Is there some other way for this?

Thanks
Nik

Comment: Did you check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911663/parsing-huge-xml-files-in-php

Comment: What do you mean? Yes it is ca 5GB .. it is 4,7 GB ;-)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167062/best-way-to-process-large-xml-in-php/8250302