# How to read gigantic xml file with PHP?

Tags: php, xml, mediawiki, large-files, wikipedia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing Huge XML Files in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911663/parsing-huge-xml-files-in-php)

I want to read wikipedia's [xml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Database_download) dump files with PHP. They are gigantic. What should I do?

Comment: Well, first things first. Why do you want to do that, and is there a subset of that information you could use instead?

Comment: @cwallenpoole, I have limited 3G connecttion. Thus inorder to decrease my bandwith usage I want to read the wiki articles from the my local server. And, the other suff such as WikiTaxi etc did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

A [SAX-based parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xml.php) should handle large files fine, as opposed to a tree-based parser.

Here, someone has [rolled their own](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/625-PHP-Generic-SAX-parsing-for-XML-made-easy.html).