# How fatal is the maximum execution timeout warning in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

Been working with the XAMP which I installed just under a year. I recently installed few frontend software for MySQL (to see which one am I comfortable with the most).

Now, for the past two days, whenever I go to `localhost/phpmysql`, I receive this warning

```
Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\lib..
```

[image]

I understand that the maximum execution time required to execute is being exceeded here. Found a few post on stackoverflow which guides you to rectification. All well and good till here.

I have a question and a concern.

**Question**

Why all of a sudden this error when, clearly remember, I did nothing to upset the default settings of the MySQL?

**Concern**

I am working on a project which uses a database (important, cannot loose it), the phpmyadmin when refreshed after the warning starts to work normally as there never was a problem. I'll need a couple of week to get done with my project. Can I continue with this timeout error without risking my database or should I try and rectify it right away?

Comment: The error is emitted by PHP, not MySQL. Quick fix - [change the execution time limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253934/set-maximum-execution-time-in-mysql-php). Better fix - analyze the PHP code that runs on this page, figure out what part of the code is really causing the problem, see if you can speed it up.

Comment: @DCoder, I did nothing to upset the default settings. Which php files to look for when I have more than 1k files on my local server?. I need to know can I still continue with my project with this error keeping in mind the MySQL is still working and why this error.

Comment: The fact the you did not change the default settings means little. There are lots of other factors that could affect the speed of the page and create this problem. If you added a lot more data to the DB recently, the code could be trying to process it all. If you changed the code to do something differently, you may have introduced a performance regression...

Comment: @DCoder, hmm, I'll take that for an answer. My concern stands though. Can I still keep using the MySQL with this time out error till I get done with my work?

Comment: Since you're using phpmyadmin, you need to [change the execution time limit in its configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17628333/1233508), not in php's own settings. That way the page won't crash, but it will still take a long time to load. I would suggest analysing what causes it to load so slowly, or using some different mysql administration tool such as MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DCoder answer is good, try to change the maximium execution time in MySQL server, also, you can try to find what query is making the noise using the slow-query-log (you can activate it and is very useful in the case of messy querys).

[Check this page for more information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/slow-query-log.html)

If you're using MySQL on windows environments, I strongly suggest to put it on a linux server, because it's lots slower over windows.

About your concern, There is no real danger about your data, and changing the slow-query-log option or maximum-execution-time option doesn't compromise the databases... but do some backup before change anything, just for extra security.

Comment: i'll check the documents you referred, +1 for the reference. Dcoder answers were satisfying.