# How to increase mysql query execution time

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using mysql database with `codeigniter` framework.
In that join more then 5 tables at a time. MySql query is fine and it produce result correctly, but it's taking too much time to produce result approx `9-12 sec`. 
How can I increase the execution time of query.

```
SELECT `questions`.* FROM `questions` LEFT JOIN `universities_questions` ON `questions`.`id` = `universities_questions`.`question_id` LEFT JOIN `courses_questions` ON `questions`.`id` = `courses_questions`.`question_id` LEFT JOIN `branches_questions` ON `questions`.`id` = `branches_questions`.`question_id` LEFT JOIN `subjects_questions` ON `questions`.`id` = `subjects_questions`.`question_id` LEFT JOIN `question_types_questions` ON `questions`.`id` = `question_types_questions`.`question_id` LEFT JOIN `questions_year` ON `questions`.`id` = `questions_year`.`question_id` WHERE `questions`.`status` = '1' GROUP BY `questions`.`id` ORDER BY `questions`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Please refer this similar question :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253934/set-maximum-execution-time-in-mysql-php

Comment: I guess you mean "decrease", i.e. get the results faster? Or do you really mean "increase" the timeout before something bad happens to your application? ;-)

Comment: ya.exactly decerase. nut i mean, increase mean, produce result faster.

Comment: @Hemdip thanx for your efforts, but its not execution error.

Comment: Then the starting point is (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html). Please add the table definitions (preferrably the exact output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE questions`, `SHOW CREATE TABLE universities_questions` and so on) and the exact result of `EXPLAIN SELECT questions.* FROM ...`. Some sample data (again preferrably in the form of valid `INSERT INTO ...` statements) would be nice, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use php sleep function if you don't want to mess with your sql...

```
sleep(10);
```

Above line will delay execution of any code bellow of this line for 10 seconds.
[Here is the php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php)