# getting error while importing sql file

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Getting an error while importing sql file.

**Error message:** `Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\sql-parser\src\Utils\BufferedQuery.php on line 359`

Comment: Try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253934/set-maximum-execution-time-in-mysql-php

Comment: At the beginning of your script you can add.

ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1);

Comment: thanks guys,
change in php.ini - replace max_execution_time with ini_set('max_execution_time', 120);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set maximum execution time in MYSQL / PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253934/set-maximum-execution-time-in-mysql-php)