# How to properly run a query that needs a lot of Processing without Getting Error

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, server, laravel-5.8

I am working on an Online E-Learning website with Laravel 5.8 and I need to run a query for **updating exam results of users** that have been participated in the exam.

Here is the Controller method for updating exam scores:

```
public function compute($oleId)
    {
        try {
            ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
            set_time_limit(0);

            DB::beginTransaction();

            /* Get the Exam */
            $exam = OlympiadExam::query()->where('ole_id', $oleId)->first();

            /* Calculate the score of Exam */
            if ($exam->ole_is_main == '0') {
                foreach ($exam->olympiadExamExecution as $execution) {
                    $questions = $execution->load('olympiadExamExecutionQuestion.olympiadExamQuestion');
                    $all = $exam->ole_question_count;
                    $notAnswered = $questions->olympiadExamExecutionQuestionNotAnswered->where('oee_oex_id', $execution->oex_id)->count();
                    $answered = $all - $notAnswered;
                    $truthy = $questions->olympiadExamExecutionQuestionTruthy->where('oee_oex_id', $execution->oex_id)->count();
                    $falsy = $all - ($truthy + $notAnswered);

                    $score = (float)($truthy - ($falsy / 3));
                    $percentage = (float)((($truthy * 3) - $falsy) / ($all * 3)) * 100;

                    $prePositive = (float)$percentage * ($exam->ole_percent_effect / 100);
                    $percentPositive = ($prePositive > 0) ? $prePositive : 0;
                    $percentFinal = (($percentage + $percentPositive) > 100) ? 100 : ($percentage + $percentPositive);
                    $scoreFinal = ((($percentFinal * $all) / 100) > $all) ? $all : ($percentFinal * ($all / 100));

                    $examResult = [
                        'oex_correct_answer_count' => $truthy,
                        'oex_wrong_answer_count' => $falsy,
                        'oex_no_answer_count' => $notAnswered,
                        'oex_score' => $score,
                        'oex_percent' => $percentage,
                        'oex_percent_positive' => $percentPositive,
                        'oex_percent_final' => $percentFinal,
                        'oex_score_final' => $scoreFinal,
                    ];

                    OlympiadExamExecution::query()->where('oex_id', $execution->oex_id)->update($examResult);
                }
            }

            $candidates = OlympiadExamExecution::query()->where('oex_ole_id', $oleId)->pluck('oex_percent_final')->toArray();
            if (!empty($candidates)) {
                $this->computeRank($candidates);
            }
            DB::commit();
            session()->flash('computeStatus', 'Process for calculating score completed');
            return redirect()->back();
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            DB::rollBack();
            session()->flash('computeStatus', 'Process for calculating score is going wrong');
            return redirect()->back();
        }

    }
```

Now this method works fine with for **a few users** that have been participated in the exam but does not work out for **large number of users** (about 500 users).

Therefore I tried setting `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` and `set_time_limit(0);` before the query runs but still does not workout and shows this message:

[image]

So I wonder what's going wrong that cause this error?

How can I properly make this processing works for large number of users?

I would REALLY appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys *because my life depends on this*...

Comment: Your query is likely exceeding the [`max execution time`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253934/set-maximum-execution-time-in-mysql-php) which is why you're getting the timeout. A couple of solutions are to either increase the limit, or run your query as a [task](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling).

Comment: @Peppermintology You mean `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` ? How can I set to **unlimited** ?

Comment: Don't, that's not recommended. Use another solution such as tasks or chuncking as suggested by [Adnan Siddique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70799429/281278).

Comment: @Peppermintology I'm using the Model relationship to access foreach: `foreach ($exam->olympiadExamExecution as $execution) {`. I don't know how to implement chunk method here!

Comment: @Peppermintology Also I tried setting `ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);` (because I'm running this query with an authorized Admin user so there's no need to worry), but I get this error: **SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction**

Comment: `$exam->olympiadExamExecution->chunk(100, function ( $executions) {
    foreach ($executions as $execution) {
        // ...
    }
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a chunk method in laravel for queuing large data.
You can chunk the data and try importing datas
Here is the link for reference: [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#chunking-results)

I hope this link will help you.
Here is what documentation says about it.

> If you need to work with thousands of database records, consider using the chunk method provided by the DB facade. This method retrieves a small chunk of results at a time and feeds each chunk into a closure for processing. For example, let's retrieve the entire users table in chunks of 100 records at a time:

Comment: Would you show me how to implement `chunk` in my Controller method ?

Comment: At least go with the documentation once. You will find methods for implementing your query.

One of the query from the documentation is here.

`DB::table('users')->where('active', false)
    ->chunkById(100, function ($users) {
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            DB::table('users')
                ->where('id', $user->id)
                ->update(['active' => true]);
        }
    });`

Comment: I have read about the documentation, but I'm using the Model relationship to access foreach: `foreach ($exam->olympiadExamExecution as $execution) {` ...

Comment: Therefore I don't where to implement the `chunk` method in this case...

Comment: `$exam->olympiadExamExecution->chunk(100, function ( $executions) {
    foreach ($executions as $execution) {
        // ...
    }
});`