# Process large XML text nodes in PHP

Tags: php, xml

In [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911663/parsing-huge-xml-files-in-php) question it is addressed how to parse large XML documents in PHP using streams, so that the whole document does not have to be put in memory.

However, the `XMLReader` class seems not fit for parsing huge *text nodes* inside an XML document. Since an API I'm using sends base64-encoded files as values of an XML document, together with some metadata, I'm looking for a way to stream those text nodes, rather than returning the value as a string:

```
<?php
$reader = XMLReader::open($someStream);

// $reader->read() until a node is reached

// The following puts the whole text node in memory, rather than creating a stream
$content = $reader->value; 
?>
```

Is it possible to turn `$reader->value` into a stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have come up with is using the low-level XML Parser of PHP and some streaming functions.

```
$input = fopen('input.xml', 'r');
$output = fopen('output.txt', 'w');
stream_filter_append($output, 'convert.base64-decode');
```

These are passed to a class which creates an XML Parser:

```
public function __construct($input, $output) {
    // ...
    $this->xml = xml_parser_create();
    xml_set_object($this->xml, $this);
    xml_set_element_handler($this->xml, 'start', 'end');
    xml_set_character_data_handler($this->xml, 'character');
}
```

The `start` and `end` methods are used to find the correct element in the XML, and the `character` method writes the contents to the output stream:

```
protected function character($parser, $data)
{
    if ($this->match()) {
        fwrite($this->output, $data);
    }
}
```

The efficient part is where we call the parser, which only reads manageable chunks at a time:

```
while ($data = fread($this->input, $bufferSize = 1024)) {
    xml_parse($this->xml, $data, feof($this->input) or $this->done);
}
```

The `$this->done` can be set in the `start` or `end` handlers, and in my case I completely removed the handlers as soon as a match was found.

Since these old php functions don't throw, some safety checks must still be implemented of course.