# How to get large amount of XML data from live XML url without browser crashing?

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to pull XML data from a large XML feed url. The feed is gigantic. When I load it in Chrome after about 15 minutes my browser crashes. I'm basically just trying to get all the XML data out of the feed. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't use chrome, use a command line tool like wget or curl and redirect the output to a file.

Comment: If you want to process is - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911663/parsing-huge-xml-files-in-php.

Comment: Would a curl like this work: curl www.xmlurl.com -o "file_1.txt"