# SimpleXMLElement::asXML(): Memory allocation failed : creating output

Tags: php, memory, simplexml

With PHP CLI, when can I get this error:

```
SimpleXMLElement::asXML(): Memory allocation failed : creating output
```

Does it because I don't have enough memory or should I suspect anything else?

Comment: Increase php`memory_limit` or use `XMLWriter` it support flush buffer.

Comment: Increase the memory available for the PHP script and try again, you will have your answer.

Comment: That sounds like the memory allocation is running out inside the XML parser, rather than in PHP - it's the same error as reported in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60950500/simplexml-load-string-memory-allocation-failed Can you come up with some example code that reproduces the problem?