# Processing huge XML files

Tags: php-7, laravel-7

I am working on an application which has below requirements -

1. Download a ZIP file from a server.
2. Uncompress the ZIP file, get the content (which is in XML format) from this file.
3. Process the content and insert it into DB.

The concern here is that the XML file may be of Huge size say like 2 GB!

What's the Laravel/PHP way of doing that without killing the server?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911663/parsing-huge-xml-files-in-php?

Comment: Yes @Don'tPanic, or the use of file streaming.

Comment: You should look into a new-ish PHP structure called a Generator. It allows you to generate each successive piece of data as you need it, rather than loading the entire pile of data into memory.